# Why won't my string value return?

Tags: java, string, return, return-value

I'm trying to run a factorial program that will outprint the number being factored and its factorial. I used a helper method to do the computing and made it a String method. Now when I go to return the string to my main program it won't work. I'm getting an error message saying "cannot find symbol". I've tried renaming the variable many times and it just doesn't seem to recognize it. Please help!

```
public class BigIntergerFactorial {

    public static String factorial(int x) {
        int result = 1;

        for (int n = x; n > 0; n--) {
            result = n * result;
            String Run = (x + ", " + result);

        }
        return Run;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        while (x <= 30) {
            String result1 = factorial(x);
            System.out.println(result1);
            x = x + 1;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is now, this program won't compile. The `String Run` has a scope limited to the for-loop, while you are returning outside the loop.

*Secondly, I am not commenting on the correctness/incorrectness of your code since that seems to be outside the scope of the question you have posted.*

This will solve the problem of returning from this function.

```
public static String factorial(int x) {
    int result = 1;
    String run = null;
    for (int n = x; n > 0; n--) {
        result = n * result;
        run = (x + ", " + result);
    }
    return run;
}
```

Comment: @DominiqueM Sure!! It would be nice, if you could accept/upvote an answer if your issue is resolved. From [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), "Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved."